# Adding Properties to a Frame descendant

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'm pretty new to Delphi even though I used to use it many years ago (ver 2) so the Frame concept is something new to me. I understand that they work simular to Forms in that that they have an associated DFM file and are an easy way to create components (without actually creating a component, I do understand the difference between a component and a frame). I created a simple Frame and wanted to add a property to it, however I thought that property would show up in the Object Inspector when I placed the Frame on a Form but it didn't. My question is why it doesn't?

Comment: we would need to see your declaration of the frame componant... my guess would be that the property isn't published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame would also have to be registered in the IDE for properties to show in the object inspector, see:

[Registering a custom Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876081/registering-a-custom-frame)